# Azure WebApp Service with pre-selected docker image, how to access it over ssh or bash on Kudu DebugConsole?

Tags: azure, docker, livekit

I deployed over Azure a new resource => selected a WebApp Service and selected a docker image from docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/livekit/livekit-server

Now how do I connect to the linux machine to somehow interact with the docker container? or how do I see if the livekit-server is running and on which ports is it accessible? How do I open this ports to the world?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re wanting to ssh into the host OS, you may want to look into running LiveKit on a standard VM, following the instructions here: https://docs.livekit.io/oss/deployment/vm/

As far as I can tell, Azure does not provide a way to shh into the WebApp Service host OS. While you may be able to get LiveKit working there, there’s more to LiveKit than just a web app. LiveKit includes a Websocket signaling server, a Real Time Communications server, and a TURN server all in one.